# Is there a way to develop upstart scripts on fedora 21?

Tags: fedora, systemd, upstart

I'm working on creating upstart scripts for an internal service I'm working on.  I realize systemd has triumphed over upstart, but our company already has an investment in upstart and I'm just tacking on one more (simple) service onto it.  Also, it might be a while before we upgrade to CentOS 7.  So for now, I'm just going to go with upstart.  To develop my script, I'd like to use my local machine (fedora 21).  However, fedora switched over to systemd a while ago.  Is there a way to switch my fedora back to upstart?  If not, is there a way I can at least run initctl w/out switching the whole system over to upstart?  I tried searching in yum, but came up with nothing.

```
andersonbd1@localhost:~$ sudo yum search all upstart
Loaded plugins: langpacks
=============================================================================== Matched: upstart ===============================================================================
3proxy-sysvinit.x86_64 : Legacy SysV initscripts for 3proxy server
pacemaker.x86_64 : Scalable High-Availability cluster resource manager
perdition-sysvinit.noarch : Legacy SysV initscripts for perdition
systemd.x86_64 : A System and Service Manager
```

Comment: "but our company already has an investment in upstart" I'm curious as to how much of an investment in a particular method of unix service management is possible. Especially considering it's requiring you to spend time to figure something like this out. Writing `systemd` service files isn't especially difficult, they're just ini files.

Comment: I also doubt something like this is going to be possible with Fedora, since changing the service management system would be a fundamental change to the OS. I'd imagine it would create a maintenance headache for them if they tried to support an opt-out mechanism as well.

Comment: [Here](http://patrakov.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html) is an example `systemd` unit file. The first example is only six lines long.

Comment: Just download a CentOS 6 vagrant image.

Comment: you're right - vagrant is much simpler solution.  Thanks, jordanm.